# Do I use one server or two servers if I want to serve React files AND make API calls?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I want to test out React SSR, which I'm completely new to and have no experience in (Please feel free to correct me anywhere I'm wrong, as everything I'm doing is based off of guesses!). I could be wrong, but my idea of what SSR means is that the server will serve up React files.

Currently, I'm using a Node/Express server, so I'm guessing it would look something like `app.use('/home', express.static('build'))`, where 'build' is my React folder. However, what do I do if my React application needs to make API calls to my server? Would I then require a separate Node/Express server that handles the API calls, or would I use the same one that's serving my React files? If I use the same one, what would my fetch URL be (e.g. if my server was at www.example.com, would it just be www.example.com or would it be something like '127.0.0.1')? Is what I want to do even possible? Is it useful?

Comment: Dinesh Pandiyan gave a very good reply.  Specifically: 1) You only need one server.  2) "SSR" (Server Side Rendering) means that the server *parses* the React files ... but the resulting *Javascript* (+ HTML) is sent to the client.  3) This means that your React application is *executing* on the client.  4) This, in turn, means that "127.0.0.1" will work *ONLY* if the client and server are both on the same host.  Otherwise, you *MUST* use the hostname to use the API.

Answer (score 3):

Just **one** server would be enough for your needs.

#### Server

You will need to serve your static files from one of your endpoints, preferabbly root endpoint (`/`).

You front end can call your API endpoints without using domain name. By default, API calls without domain name will go to same origin.

Let's say your server is at `example.com`.

- When you load the root domain (`http://example.com/`) in the browser, your react app will be loaded.
- While making API calls in your react app, specify the URL without domain.

Your fetch code will look like this

```
fetch('/endpoint')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then(() => {
    // do happy things
  });
```

When you don't specify domain name in fetch URL, your browser will make the API call to your root domain by default => `http://example.com/endpoint`.

In `localhost`, your API call will go to `http://localhost/endpoint` by default.

So you will never have to worry to which domain the API calls are being made.

#### SSR

You are almost right on your viewpoint of SSR

> my idea of what SSR means is that the server will serve up React files

But what it exactly means is, React applications are JavaScript applications. Without SSR, only a simple HTML with one div (mostly) will be served from the server with bundle files and your DOM will be initialized in the browser. So if you have JavaScript disabled in your browser, you will only have a white screen, which is very bad for SEO. When React applications are server rendered, your React code is executed in the server and full DOM after React initialization is sent in the response as HTML. This way, the site loads faster for the user and even if JavaScript is disabled, the page will load, which reaps SEO benefits.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! But I'm still a bit confused. So for SSR, the index.html sent to the client would then have all the elements written out, whereas without SSR, the index.html would have the div element with a script tag including the React javascript, correct?

Comment: More or less yes. For clarity, Without SSR, all your HTML code will be painted to your DOM only after React is initialized in your browser. With SSR, all your HTML code will be sent in the response and be painted in DOM before loading javascript. And again, once javascript is loaded, React will hydrate (attaching events, etc) to your DOM.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that we have this express app which will serve the React build file/s..

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 4000;

const controllers = require('./controllers');

// Read routers from express controllers.
app.use('/api/v1', controllers);
// for example: localhost:3000/api/v1/get-articles

// For React deployment.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // # npm run build #
  // Serve build version of the app.
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
  // Return all the requests that don't fit to the list of controllers routes above to our React app.
  app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
    // this index.html is where our React production bundle lives.
  });
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));

module.exports = app;
```

So, you can do it all in one server.
I hope that helps, ask me if you wish.